# Basis for Tangent Plane of Level set

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose I have a zero-level set of a function
$$
\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\, :\, f(x, y, z) = 0\}
$$
I would like to find *computationally* a general method to compute *a* basis (any!) for the tangent space at a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. How can I do that?

## Hint

I know that the gradient at a point will essentially be the normal vector of the tangent plane.
$$
\nabla f(x, y, z)|_{x_0, y_0, z_0} = \left(\partial_x f(x,y,z), \partial_y f(x,y,z), \partial_z f(x, y,z)\right)^\top|_{x_0, y_0, z_0} 
$$
I have been told (but could not verify this in ANY way) that one can find such as basis as follows:

- Compute the transpose of the Jacobian, $J_f^\top$ i.e. the gradient in this case.
- Compute its QR decomposition
- Use the $Q$ matrix of this QR decomposition as your basis

This sounds absolutely false to me. But what's a method to do this?

Comment: You already mentioned how to find a basis for the tangent space. The gradient of $f$ at the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is perpendicular to the tangent space at that point, so just compute the tangent plane i.e. the orthogonal complement of the gradient vector at that point. This is exactly analogous to the regular value theorem, which states that the tangent plane at the point $p$ is equal to $\ker( df|_p)$, where $df$ is the differential of $f$.

Comment: @C_M I know that the plane is given by all vectors that are perpendicular to the normal, but I would like to have an automated proceedure to find a basis spanning the plane. How do I do that? How would I find the orthogonal complement?

Comment: @C_M In this case $\text{ker}(df|_p) = \{v\in \mathbb{R}^3\, :\, v^\top \nabla f(x, y, z)|_{x_0, y_0, z_0}\}$ but how do I find it **computationally**?

Comment: You have that $\nabla f|_{p} = (\partial_x f(p),  \partial_y f(p),  \partial_z f(p))^\top$, and so the condition $v^\top \nabla f|_p = 0$ becomes $v_1 \partial_x f(p) + v_2 \partial_y f(p) + v_3 \partial_z f(p) = 0$ where $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)^\top$. This is just a linear equation, which can be solved in all generality.

Comment: @C_M sorry if I am asking something stupid but I still don't think I get how I would compute a basis from it. For instance, suppose $\nabla f|_p = (1, 1, 1)^\top$.Then the condition is $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 0$ but surely this doesn't give me enough information to find a basis? However there **must** be an automated method to find such a basis because a normal vector at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)^\top$ automatically defines a plane, which automatically has some basies

Comment: For the equation $ax + by + cz = 0$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and at least one of them is non-zero (I will present the case when $a \neq 0$; I am certain that you can handle the other two cases), the space of solutions is equal to $$\left\{ \left( \frac{-by-cz}{a}, y, z \right)^\top \ \mid \ y,z \in \mathbb{R}  \right\}, $$ and this is just equal to $$ \mathrm{span} \left\{ (-b/a, 1, 0)^\top, (-c/a, 0, 1)^\top \right\},$$ so the basis for the space is solutions is the set $$ \{(-b/a, 1, 0)^\top, (-c/a, 0, 1)^\top \}.$$

Comment: @C_M So in general is it correct to say that if we define 
$$
b1 = \left(-\frac{\partial_y f(p)}{\partial_x f(p)}, 1, 0\right)^\top \\
b2 = \left(-\frac{\partial_z f(p)}{\partial_x f(p)}, 0, 1\right)^\top
$$
Then an orthonormal basis for the tangent plane at $p$ is given by
$$
\left\{\frac{b_1}{||b_1||}, \frac{b_2}{||b_2||}\right\}
$$
?

Comment: For the first part: yes, but only if $\partial_x f(p) \neq 0$. The orthonormal basis may not be what you wrote down. There is no guarantee that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are perpendicular to one another, unless $\partial_y f(p) \cdot \partial_z f(p) = 0$.

Comment: Okay. And so if that's the case instead what do we do? My guess is that we choose the non-zero partial derivative to go at the denominator, i.e. rather than using the substitution $x = \frac{-by -cz}{a}$ we use either $y = \frac{-ax-cz}{b}$ if $b\neq 0$ or $z = \frac{-ax-by}{c}$ if $c\neq 0$?

Comment: @C_M Ooh fair. So then we should probably some method to find an orthonormal basis from $b_1$ and $b_2$?

Comment: To find an orthonormal basis, just use the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: yes! Which I guess then connects back to what I asked in my question cause the QR decomposition does perform a Graham-Schmidt process

Comment: At least one of $f_x,f_y,f_z$ has to be nonzero, say, $f_z$. Let $f_1 = (-f_z,0,f_x)$ and $f_2=(0,-f_z,f_y)$. If you need an orthonormal basis, you can do Gram-Schmidt. Here, this is easily described explicitly: Set $e_1 = f_1/|f_1|$ and $e_2 = v/|v$, where $v = f_2 - (f_2\cdot e_1)e_1$.

Comment: @Deane would it make sense to use SVD on the normal vector?

Comment: And then keep the $U$ matrix

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by SVD on the normal vector. And why? Isn't my algorithm simple enough to implement directly?